# SQL запрос к разным таблицам с разными полями

Tags: sql, запрос

Есть 2 таблицы с разными полями. Из первой таблицы (`T1`) нужно просто получить все записи. В ней одно поле `Name` содержащее запись -
`Сковородка`
Делаю это так:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
```

И есть вторая таблица (`T2`) (`Name`, `Count`) в которой содержатся записи:

- `Сковородка` `2`
- `Кастрюля` `5`
- `Кружка` `2`
- `Сковородка` `4`

из которой нужно получить только те записи, которые содержатся в таблице `T1`, но так же нужно получить значение `Count`. Делаю это так:

```
SELECT SUM(Count) FROM T2 WHERE `Name` = 'Сковородка'
```

Как можно одним запросом получить нужные мне данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.*, (SELECT SUM([Count]) FROM T2 WHERE T2.Name = T1.Name) FROM T1
```

Comment: данный запрос выдает то что мне нужно. спасибо

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин отметьте как ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если таблица T1 имеет уникальные значения в поле Name, тогда так:

```
SELECT T1.Name, SUM(T2.Count) as Count
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.Name = T2.Name
WHERE T1.Name = 'Сковородка'

GROUP BY T1.Name
```

Если значения Name не уникальные в Т1, тогда можно переписать следующим образом:

```
WITH Product AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT T1.Name
  FROM T1
)

SELECT p.Name, SUM(T2.Count) as Count
FROM Product p
JOIN T2 ON p.Name = T2.Name
WHERE p.Name = 'Сковородка'

GROUP BY p.Name
```

**Но все же необходимо использовать primary key в Т1 и foreighn key в T2.**

T1 с primary key t1_id, и поле Name

T2 c primary key t2_id, foreign key t1_id,Count

Тогда запрос будет такой (для уникальных значений Name в T1):

```
SELECT T1.Name, SUM(T2.Count) as Count
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.t1_id= T2.t1_id
WHERE T1.t1_id = 1 -- id Сковородки

GROUP BY T1.Name
```

Comment: Таблица T1 может иметь сколько угодно повторяющихся значений. в обе таблицы добавил поле id с автоикриментом. И мне нужно не конкретно ссылаться на запись или ее айди а что бы при выборке SELECT * FROM T1, значение поля Name подставлялось в запрос SELECT SUM(Count) FROM T2 WHERE `Name` = 'тут значение'

Comment: Тут необходимо разобраться в структуре хранимых данных тогда. Должна быть таблица, которая содержит уникальные значения Сковородка, Кастрюля и т.д. своего рода справочник. Какова цель таблицы T1? Что она хранит, кто и как её использует? Какова цель таблицы T2? Судя по агрегации, которая уже там имеется, что то похоже либо на поступление товара, либо на продажу. Выбрать данные как вы хотите можно, но есть подозрение, что дальше с этой структурой вам будет всё сложнее и сложнее ...

Comment: тут все просто- нужно хранить поступивший товар и его количество. соответственно если вчера поступило 10 сковородок, а завтра поступит еще 5, а сегодня продано 2 то завтрашнее кол-во будет 13. а записи содержащие "сковородка" будет 2. при продаже товар перемещается в новую таблицу а вот при ее выборке необходимо так же отобразить кол-во остатка товара. если это можно сделать как то по другому буду рад подсказкам

Comment: Ну тут много вариантов, всё зависит от дальнейших задач. Как минимум должна быть таблица что то вроде Products со структурой вида product_id, product_name. Это справочник всех ваших товаров, там будут только уникальные записи. А таблицу операций поступления/продажи, я бы сделал как то так: ProductsOperation product_oper_id, product_id, oper_type_id, oper_date, amount. Тут поле product_id - это FK на таблицу Products, oper_type_id - ИД операции (например 1- дебет, 2-кредит), oper_date - дата операции, ну и amount - кол-во. Можно текущее состояние склада выделить в отдельную таблицу...